# Picking and assigning image

Tags: c#, .net, image, sqlite, xamarin

I'm trying to make an app like contact app,but I can't figure out how to assign image to the contact from inside the app using image picker and save the changes in a SQLite database. 
I'm developing this using xamarin forms

I have an interface

```
    public interface IPhotoPickerService
        {
            Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync();
        }
```

and in my android implementation

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhotoPickerService))]
namespace Drugs.Droid.Sevices
{

    public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
    {




        public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
        {
            // Define the Intent for getting images
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

            // Start the picture-picker activity (resumes in MainActivity.cs)
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(
                Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Photo"),
                MainActivity.PickImageId);

            // Save the TaskCompletionSource object as a MainActivity property
            MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();

            // Return Task object
            return MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

and then when I try to save the image after i picked it up
by this method

```
async void OnPickPhotoButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            var drug = (Drug)BindingContext;
            (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;

            Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();
            if (stream != null)
            {
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }

            (sender as Button).IsEnabled = true;


        }
```

how can i save the image I'm getting from stream to a sqlite database or a local folder

Comment: are you using the Media plugin?  What **specifically** are you having problems with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please research your problem and attempt a solution on your own before asking Stack Overflow. This helps to avoid open ended questions, which often go unanswered. With very few exceptions, a good rule of thumb is if you're asking how to do something and you don't have any code, you shouldn't ask Stack Overflow yet. Please ask another question when you've written some code and encounter a specific problem. Have a good day!

Comment: @Jason I'm having trouble saving an image selected from inside the app to a specific contact. also I don't use Media plugin

Comment: you need to show us the code that you are having problems with if you expect us to help you fix it.

Comment: I have Updated my question Mr.@Jason this is my first time asking here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Jason .If you want to picker image from device and save it to DB . You could use the plugin **Xam.Plugin.Media** from nuget .

#### Usage

```
async void OnPickPhotoButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

  if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
  {
     return;
  }

  var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

  if (file == null)
     return;

  image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    });
```

And you should convert the stream to Byte array so that you save them to sqlite.

```
public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
{
  var buffer = new byte[16*1024];
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
      return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

```
var imgDate = GetImageStreamAsBytes(file.GetStream());
```

For more details about the plugin you could check https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin .

Comment: thanks you helped me alot @Lucas Zhang. but now because i have image views in more than one place i use binding but now when i select the image i get this error :       (Binding: System.Byte[] can not be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource')

Comment: You could create a new thread with more details so that people can help you better .